# Is there a better way to pick a winner for rock paper scissors?

Tags: python

Learning python casually, and decided to give rock paper scissors a go as a quick project. Went pretty smooth, but I got really caught up in the process of trying to shorten the code you use to compare the results.

```
def check_results(ai, self):
    if ai == self:
        return 'tralf'
    if self == 'rock':
        if ai == 'paper':
            return False
        else:
            return True
    if self == 'scissors':
        if ai == 'rock':
            return False
        else:
            return True
    if self == 'paper':
        if ai == 'scissors':
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

> ai and self, as you can probably guess, are the computers pick and the players pick just being passed in.

Something about having to hard code this was very very unsatisfying to me, and I spent about 20 minutes sort of refusing to do it, and just trying out random stuff to see if I could shorten it.

The one thing I tried was to involve something where you get the index of both players choice from a list, and use that to compare them by running it through a separate list. Couldn't get it to work, or at least couldn't get it to work in a way that was better than just hard coding it, so I gave up and did it the boring way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, to start, `if <bool>: return False; else: return True` is a long way of writing `return not <bool>`

Comment: Maybe beside the point, but what's "tralf"? Is that your language's word for "draw"?

Comment: no i just wanted a third option for a tie lmao. true + false = tralf.

Answer (score 1):

At the cost of readability and error-checking, something like this maybe:

```
def did_player_win(player_choice, computer_choice):
    choices = ['scissors', 'paper', 'rock']
    # The order in which the strings appear in the list is important.
    # scissors beats paper
    # paper beats rock
    # rock beats scissors (wraps around)

    return choices[(choices.index(player_choice) + 1) % len(choices)] == computer_choice

player_choice = 'paper'
computer_choice = 'rock'
print(did_player_win(player_choice, computer_choice))
```

That doesn't make for great source code though. There's no shame in being verbose (future self will thank you:)

```
def did_player_win(player_choice, computer_choice):
    choices = {
        'rock': 'scissors',
        'paper': 'rock',
        'scissors': 'paper'
    }

    return choices[player_choice] == computer_choice
```

Comment: What about draw?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using python 3.10's match-case (pattern-matching):

```
def check_results(ai, self):
    if ai == self:
        return 'tralf'
    match (ai, self):
        case ('scissor', 'paper') | ('paper', 'rock') | ('rock', 'scissor'):  # cases where you lose
            return False
        case ('scissor', 'rock') | ('paper', 'scissor') | ('rock', 'paper'):  # cases where you win
            return True


print(check_results('rock', 'rock'))
print(check_results('rock', 'paper'))
print(check_results('paper', 'rock'))
print(check_results('rock', 'scissor'))
```

Result:

```
tralf
True
False
False
```

Comment: Match-case is overkill for this. You could just use a `set`: `wins = {('scissors', 'paper'), ('paper', 'rock'), ('rock', 'scissors')}` then `if (computer, player) in wins: return False; elif (player, computer) in wins: return True`

Answer (score 0):

My solution to my son’s school assignment. Had a couple of extra requirements: You must declare the winner, and you must use a descriptive verb to state the outcome of the contest.

```
all_wins = {
    ("rock", "scissors"): "crushes",
    ("paper", "rock"): "covers",
    ("scissors", "paper"): "cuts"
}

def result_string(player_a, player_b):
    if player_a == player_b:
        return f"Both did {player_a}. They tied."
    elif (player_a, player_b) in all_wins:
        verb = all_wins[(player_a, player_b)]
        return f"{player_a} {verb} {player_b}! player A wins."
    else:
        verb = all_wins[(player_b, player_a)]
        return f"{player_b} {verb} {player_a}! player B wins."
```

Test:

```
choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
for aaa in choices:
    for bbb in choices:
        print(result_string(aaa, bbb))
```

Gives:

```
Both did rock. They tied.
paper covers rock! player B wins.
rock crushes scissors! player A wins.
paper covers rock! player A wins.
Both did paper. They tied.
scissors cuts paper! player B wins.
rock crushes scissors! player B wins.
scissors cuts paper! player A wins.
Both did scissors. They tied.
```